# Choice of stochastic integral picking the forward point in Riemann sum approximation and reversibility?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-calculus, rough-paths

Consider the standard Riemann sum approximation of a stochastic integral (w.r.t Brownian motion for example) which is given by
\begin{align}
\int_0^t \sigma(X_s) \circ_{\lambda}dB_s \approx \sum_{i=1}^N (\lambda\sigma(X_{s_{i+1}}) + (1-\lambda)\sigma(X_{s_i}))(B_{s_{i+1}}-B_{s_i}) \, ,
\end{align}
where both $\sigma: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $X_t$ are as nice as you want them to be. It is well-known that $\lambda=0$ corresponds to (an approximation of) the Itô integral and $\lambda=\frac12$ corresponds to the Stratonovich integral, both of which have some nice properties that may be useful in different contexts. For Itô, we get a martingale and for Stratonovich we get the standard rules of calculus.

There is another choice, $\lambda=1$, that seems to be distinguished but I was only be able to find a few references to it and it seems to be mainly studied in the physics literature. It is referred to as the Klimontovich or Hänggi-Klimontovich integral. It is important/distinguished because the process associated to the following SDE on $\mathbb{R}$
\begin{align}
dX_t = -\sigma^2(X_t) V'(X_t) \, \mathrm{d}t  + \sqrt{2\beta^{-1}}\sigma(X_t)\circ_{\lambda}dB_t \, ,
\end{align}
is reversible with respect to the correct invariant measure $\mu=Z^{-1}e^{-\beta V} \mathrm{d}x$ if and only if $\lambda=1$. This is quite straightforward to check by hand by computing the appropriate correction w.r.t Itô and then checking that the generator is (formally) self-adjoint in $L^2(\mathbb{R},\mu)$. Thus, like Itô and Stratonovich, the Klimontovich integral has its own nice property that may prove useful in a particular context. The purpose of this question is twofold:

(1). Firstly, what is the intuitive reason that choosing the forward point in the Riemann sum approximation gives us reversibility at the level of the solution of the SDE? Any kind of heuristic explanation or useful reference would be welcome.

(2.) Secondly, I can break down the question further: In the context of the theory of rough paths all I need to do to choose a particular stochastic integral is to specify the first iterated integral of Brownian motion, i.e. "$\int_0^t B_s dB_s$". If I choose it to be $\frac{B_t^2}{2}$ which is what I would expect from the standard rules of calculus I get a stochastic integral that respects these rules, i.e. the Stratonovich integral. If I choose it to be $\frac{B_t^2}{2}- \frac t2$ I am imposing that its a martingale and so I get Itô. The question arises then what am I doing for Klimontovich. I know the choice I have to make, namely $\frac{B_t^2}{2} + \frac t2$, but I want to know what property I am imposing at the level of the first iterated integral. It cannot be reversibility as reversibility does not make sense till I have an invariant measure. Is it something more subtle or is it nothing at all? Again, any help would be welcome.

Comment: related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391023/intuition-elegant-reason-for-why-langevin-diffusion-converges-to-exp-u/391044#391044